# "Room for improvement" of vs. with

Tags: grammar, phrases, prepositions

Which of the following two is correct?

> 1. there is still room for improvement **with** the implemented tool
> 2. there is still room for improvement **of** the implemented tool

I used the *with* alternative in my thesis, but was told to use *of* instead.
However, the way I see it both are correct with the first one meaning "there is room for improvement *concerning* the tool", while the second one says "there is room for - improvement of the tool". I am simply trying to say that the tool can still be improved and am now unsure whether the sentence can be used with *with*.

Comment: Which do you think is correct, and why? Also, what is the context? More detail is needed.

Comment: @Hank Edited the question.

Comment: As I read these options, improvement "with" the implemented tool has the implication that the improvement would come through better or more efficient use of the tool, while improvement "of" the implemented tool states clearly that the tool can be improved to do a better or more efficient job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is somewhat ambiguous; it is not obvious *what exactly* is to be improved - the tool itself or something else (by means of the tool). The second sentence states clearly that *the tool* is the object of improvement.

Comment: I agree: the first sounds as if you are using the tool to make an improvement in something else.